# Filter values from NSMutableArray using NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nspredicate

```
country=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Afghanistan",
             @"Albania",
             @"Algeria",
             @"American Samoa",
             @"Andorra",
             @"Angola",
             @"Anguilla",
             @"Antigua and Barbuda",
             @"Argentina",
             @"Armenia",
             @"Aruba",
             @"Ascension Island",
             @"Australia",nil];

    NSString *value=@"Al";
    NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",value];
    NSArray *filterValue  = [country filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

I have a NSMutableArray with list of countries.I tried to filter values with NSPredicate.It is not working.What is wrong with my code?any help will appreicated.thanks in advance

Comment: What's not working? What result do you see? What result do you want?

Comment: [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html) has everything you need to know.

Comment: If i give Al the countries which are start with Al should be filtered

Comment: BTW, what you posted won't even compile unless you've defined "value" (with a lowercase v) somewhere else in your app, since the code you show has Value = @"b" with a capital v.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
NSString *value=@"Al";
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] %@",value];
```

Notice that "value" is lowercase in both places that it's used.